# What are the valid values for type organization publicKeys from Platform of Trust's Product API?

Tags: api, platform, platform-of-trust

Looking at [product creation documentation](https://docs.oftrust.net/#products-v1), I have a question:

- under **organizationPublicKeys**, there is **type**.

What are the valid values and significance of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **type** of the organization public key should be the string "RsaSignature2018" which tells that the public key is an RSA key. At the moment we do not support any other key types.